# android studio/flutter/dart: how to select the dart sdk?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I have installed flutter which should come with dart

```
C:\Users\nicktohzyu>flutter --version
Flutter 1.22.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7891006299 (4 weeks ago) • 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
Engine • revision ae90085a84
Tools • Dart 2.10.4
```

but I'm having difficulty selecting the dart sdk in android studio
[image]

Answer (score 1):

solved by selecting `C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk` instead

Answer (score 0):

In the below image you can see `Enable dart support for the following module` there you have to select your project.

[Please open it for clear answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b55WX.png)